# createWriteStream close event

Tags: node.js

I'm piping from an FTP read stream (https://npmjs.org/package/ftp) into a simple fs write stream. I am waiting on the close event of the fs stream and then quitting my application, but when I do this, it appears that the entire file has not been flushed to disk when I look at it later.

The code looks like this:

```
 var fstream = fs.createWriteStream(savePath + file);
 fstream.once('close',deferred.resolve);
 stream.pipe(fstream);
```

When this promise is done, I quit the application.  Is there some other event I should be listening on to know if the file has indeed been flushed to disk by the OS?  This issue is especially problematic on my production box which has large disk buffers (8M).

I think it might be a node issue.  I've opened this issue:

https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6438

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should listen to [`finish` event](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish) instead.

Comment: A `close` event on a writable stream? Does that even exist? Also, flushing the data to disk after `close(2)` is the duty of the kernel and not the process, so exiting the process should not prevent the data from being flushed.

Answer (score 1):

You should listen to the Writestream `finish` event - https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish